# Crear PDF de Varias Paginas con JSPDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, jspdf

Hola amigos estoy tratando de crear un pdf para imprimir unos boletos, estoy usando boostrap para darle formato a html y para crear el PDF jspdf y html2pdf

El problema es que quiero acomodar 4 boletos en una hoja carta, pero mi código solo me genera 1 pagina y solo salen 2 boletos completos, ¿alguien sabe como puedo hacer para que cree mas hojas y salgan todos los boletos?

este es mi html:

```
<div id="boletera" class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6" id="boletos">
            <div class="col-sm-5 carta">
                <div class="thumbnail"><img class="foto-perfil-nav responsive " src="recursos/imagenes_eventos/covers/4castle copia.jpg" alt="Castle on the Hill - Ed Sheeran">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h5>Castle on the Hill - Ed Sheeran</h5>
                        <p> <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> 02/25/2017 <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 20:00</p>
                        <p> <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> TEATRO ZARAGOZA TIJUANA</p>
                        <p> Zona: PREFERENTE. Asiento: A16. Precio: $1000</p>
                        <p> <img id="bol40" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAHAAAACOCAYAAADpeIwiAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAABY1JREFUeAHtmk9oHFUcx39btiUBURBMpREE9VDQRTzZ46CnXNaLxxQvMleDF4mC2vUg9WQuLXjJKadctJfk0ks9xJYGSkTMIUVTcJGspJAUsrADzzez+6bJMN/ptjB0v+13QvL2fd+f+e73s29m35CG84fpoE3gFK1zGc8SEEDyD4IACiB5AuT2tQIFkDwBcvtagQJIngC5fa1AcoDNcf03Go0TXcMDnKCHeugU9FAP5aP6FdvDuDBfaC/WQ79QFttDPbQX5wl6KEN7qIcSzRPaQ1nsF/Qwb2gv1ov9Qh2VWoEoGRJdAElAIZsCiJIh0QWQBBSyKYAoGRJdAElAIZsCiJIh0QWQBBSyKYAoGRJdAElAIZsCiJIh0QWQBBSyKYAoGRJdAElAIZsCiJIh0QWQBBSyKYAoGRJdAElAIZsCiJIh0QWQBBSyKYAoGRJdAElAIZsCiJIh0QWQBBSyKYAoGRJdAElAIZsCiJIh0QWQBBSyKYAoGRJdAElAIZsCiJIh0QWQBBSyKYAoGRJdAElAIZsCiJIh0QWQBBSyKYAoGRJdAElAIZsCiJIh0QWQBBSyKYAoGRJdAElAIZsCiJIh0QWQBBSyKYAoGRJdAElAIZsCiJIh0QWQBBSyKYAoGRJdAElAIZsCiJIh0QWQBBSyKYAoGRJdAElAIZsCiJIh0QWQBBSyKYAoGRJdAElAIZsCiJIh0QWQBBSyKYAoGRJdAElAIZsCiJIh0QWQBBSyKYAoGRJdAElAIZsCiJIh0QWQBBSyKYAoGRJdAElAIZsCiJIh0QWQBBSyKYAoGRJdAElAIZsCiJIh0QWQBBSyKYAoGRJdAElAIZsCiJIh0QWQBBSyKYAoGRJdAElAIZsCiJIh0QWQBBSyKYAoGRJdAElAIZsCiJIh0QWQBBSyKYAoGRJdAElAIZsCiJIh0QWQBBSyKYAoGRJdAElAIZsCiJIh0QWQBBSyKYAoGRJdAElAIZsCiJIh0RvOHyReZbMkAa3AklCYJAFkolXiVQBLQmGSBJCJVolXASwJhUkSQCZaJV4FsCQUJukZAdi3Xu++9cdK3vftdq3b7Y3Zf6xJn1qnZwLgr9/N2czMyzbd+NLuJjjL/r11u9iYtpnZWZudnfH9L9r63fGw41mfckv6JIb5GOyspk+SRr9tt3EI3s3hhmuHftG8i6NjY/bBGALZCDxWWNx3V9sBRFq23SYAuLnUHkJuL7m9bMa9fGy0tFFxjsluogb4z1ongzJ/9Re3HFcB3HWd1hD08p9HOZHBzspo5S663VzlesF7D0y27dLc1/7qOW9fffqBnfm34l704D+7/XvaHtuFt6byjs3X37eFrPaHdR/kMtULWoC/XfnCfvJRx6vf2vlm0w6qYm+avZi2t9+z1/zr/GietXf9jTE9zgwLur+UAJPuNYs/u2bW6tg3H7/pQ08sX1fHAdHheHzDhAD79vOljyy9Ii788ImdSxJLkgM7yJbgX7Z1Z9t69yv2Eo+f0WSP4Lple7dHmw+3A2FbUChblwvfKg/DmAW3Mzj+jnfdYja2YvtxvPsEvuZbgVOv2odRuiha/qf8+HzunZMNUy/Z25nyo93cfbg6k3u37PtMf8Neya/BJ4dOfG0CP1RPYMnvB7ONeeRugH3gxuVouGWIV9ywy5FbjVuZFnVuPME5J2MI9T7QuYFb64w26PlltOWWt0oo7l130ahPK+64TjwCapG7vnfiujoZZMZ0wQ9wMYAYbtT9Ja8coA9kf2vF+cvuaPOelh72JvFzNP+enr//Suv3bPvvAzt9emDTZ8/buRcm/i5XafD5A1gZB18j37dQvoxrdSyAtcZb/+QCWH/GtZ5BAGuNt/7JBbD+jGs9gwDWGm/9kwtg/RnXegYBrDXe+if/H7g3Br4fb/jPAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5 carta">
                <div class="thumbnail"><img class="foto-perfil-nav responsive " src="recursos/imagenes_eventos/covers/4castle copia.jpg" alt="Castle on the Hill - Ed Sheeran">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h5>Castle on the Hill - Ed Sheeran</h5>
                        <p> <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> 02/25/2017 <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 20:00</p>
                        <p> <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> TEATRO ZARAGOZA TIJUANA</p>
                        <p> Zona: PREFERENTE. Asiento: A15. Precio: $1000</p>
                        <p> <img id="bol41" src="data:image/png;base64,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"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5 carta">
                <div class="thumbnail"><img class="foto-perfil-nav responsive " src="recursos/imagenes_eventos/covers/4castle copia.jpg" alt="Castle on the Hill - Ed Sheeran">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h5>Castle on the Hill - Ed Sheeran</h5>
                        <p> <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> 02/25/2017 <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 20:00</p>
                        <p> <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> TEATRO ZARAGOZA TIJUANA</p>
                        <p> Zona: PREFERENTE. Asiento: A14. Precio: $1000</p>
                        <p> <img id="bol42" src="data:image/png;base64,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"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5 carta">
                <div class="thumbnail"><img class="foto-perfil-nav responsive " src="recursos/imagenes_eventos/covers/4castle copia.jpg" alt="Castle on the Hill - Ed Sheeran">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h5>Castle on the Hill - Ed Sheeran</h5>
                        <p> <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> 02/25/2017 <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 20:00</p>
                        <p> <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> TEATRO ZARAGOZA TIJUANA</p>
                        <p> Zona: PREFERENTE. Asiento: A13. Precio: $1000</p>
                        <p> <img id="bol43" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAHAAAACOCAYAAADpeIwiAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAABZ9JREFUeAHtmsFrY1UYxb/IzNCKgrqowxREcGs2/gESdVWQNxvdpehCgivtzG5GUCau6sq6MLQIHZBZDCNouxkXWqUuuopIRBihRQpO0AnTQlNIIA+uN29yaxLvYRJX73TOK+Hlnvfd9OT83neT90jB+c200SbwGK1zGc8SEEDyE0EABZA8AXL76kABJE+A3L46UADJEyC3rw4kB3hmUv+FQmGkNNzACXoYh6Kgh3HYo7qgj88Lepgf9uN1QQ/14fj4ONSFPToe9FAX9uF1w3jSuvH68DphfhiP14Ux2qsDUTIkugCSgEI2BRAlQ6ILIAkoZFMAUTIkugCSgEI2BRAlQ6ILIAkoZFMAUTIkugCSgEI2BRAlQ6ILIAkoZFMAUTIkugCSgEI2BRAlQ6ILIAkoZFMAUTIkugCSgEI2BRAlQ6ILIAkoZFMAUTIkugCSgEI2BRAlQ6ILIAkoZFMAUTIkugCSgEI2BRAlQ6ILIAkoZFMAUTIkugCSgEI2BRAlQ6ILIAkoZFMAUTIkugCSgEI2BRAlQ6ILIAkoZFMAUTIkugCSgEI2BRAlQ6ILIAkoZFMAUTIkugCSgEI2BRAlQ6ILIAkoZFMAUTIkugCSgEI2BRAlQ6ILIAkoZFMAUTIkugCSgEI2BRAlQ6ILIAkoZFMAUTIkugCSgEI2BRAlQ6ILIAkoZFMAUTIkugCSgEI2BRAlQ6ILIAkoZFMAUTIkugCSgEI2BRAlQ6ILIAkoZFMAUTIkugCSgEI2BRAlQ6ILIAkoZFMAUTIkugCSgEI2BRAlQ6ILIAkoZFMAUTIkugCSgEI2BRAlQ6ILIAkoZFMAUTIkugCSgEI2BRAlQ6ILIAkoZFMAUTIkugCSgEI2BRAlQ6ILIAkoZFMAUTIkugCSgEI2BRAlQ6ILIAkoZFMAUTIkugCSgEI2BRAlQ6ILIAkoZFMAUTIkugCSgEI2BRAlQ6ILIAkoZFMAUTIkugCSgEI2BRAlQ6IXnN9IvMpmJAF1YCQUJkkAmWhFvApgJBQmSQCZaEW8CmAkFCZJAJloRbwKYCQUJumUAOxaq3Vo3UmS7x772qY1my3rppNMyHfNqQD408cLNjf3jM0WrtoegtLds+tXF60w+6Svnbf5+TmbPfuKfba1l29CD3PXvxPDvPV2b/XvJA0eidtpx95Nx91IQo25pFJx5eK/41r9IDaJQiPvwEP74vKbI+fouZFRGMzYS4vLVrlSs8a9jm2srtqXjbZtLBWzgpvf/R4K+fYUpxkwefd2Neu8cm3DrVf6HZW4erQD4y/Qrq9k85OVeryAQOXtwPSOXVv40HdM2T5451U799eUzZO27KvVr7NJR1NOzVU5wUkWtbizkmTdU7m16493XC37jHt4B/bubrulpOT84pnNN6u6/V70X1CIlB2YNjet8v6mWbFqH73xgm+I1GZCW5wJT+L79P5v9unmj/bryeE/bb850QXIyYw8PSEE2LVvrl3MACx98pZdSFNL0yM7ytbBP6zxyx1rHaJrCbOZ4rvWabft3u6OVZM+ijV7+fU1O8wTlWm8UKwTwyY7dedzHyx/8X1xeWd4Bn5+sO1K2Wuhyw88NS9H+Dpw5ry95lP366f/i2+XF16MHxhXz5rdH9fIxnwA7YK994Mz5xrW8L8G8Z3gHwdWK/WTL9l229nbxSdGMKTNLbu0eMmuf/uzHZ+srl3b+nxt8Fl43p46+RAdmZr/QV6Wgv/no+duVx98G/VJD5bVoltvjF4MtuvLQ0tu0ZX9nZhk6E5Med2fCqRb/wwm3jzAK6UhOA8gjgP0Heq+ry39p84vw656o+6IryLco/WrtPTYmvt/21Gv5xv2cXv2+efsadalc7C4P1oA8/+JNrVDwi8xU7/HUz1BAMnxCqAAkidAbl8dKIDkCZDbVwcKIHkC5Pb/AY7VkoS5YO7uAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5 carta">
                <div class="thumbnail"><img class="foto-perfil-nav responsive " src="recursos/imagenes_eventos/covers/4castle copia.jpg" alt="Castle on the Hill - Ed Sheeran">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h5>Castle on the Hill - Ed Sheeran</h5>
                        <p> <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> 02/25/2017 <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 20:00</p>
                        <p> <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> TEATRO ZARAGOZA TIJUANA</p>
                        <p> Zona: PREFERENTE. Asiento: A12. Precio: $1000</p>
                        <p> <img id="bol44" src="data:image/png;base64,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"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Este es el script

```
$("#imprimir-pdf").click(function() {
  var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
  var boletos = $('#boletos');

  html2pdf(boletos, pdf, function(pdf){
     pdf.save('sample-file.pdf');
   });

});
```

y así es como se ve cuando lo renderiso  en pdf

[image: mi pdf]

Comment: Consulta la [docuemntación](http://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/global.html#addPage) y revisa [estas](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24013355/4092887) [respuestas](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25907361/4092887).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encontre la respuesta solo hay que usar la siguiente etiqueta:

```
<pagebreak/>
```

Comment: Lo bueno si breve dos veces bueno.